# Statistically comparing positions from two track datasets?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-statistics, statistics, tracking

I have two datasets with positions that I need to compare. One would be the "observed" positions (someone took the GPS positions manually) and the other one was calculated using a software. To use statistical terms, I will call the latter one the "estimated" positions. These two dataset mostly overlap, but plotting both datasets is not enough, I need to conduct some kind of statistical analysis to show the results.
Can anyone suggest a tool in ArcMap that I could use for this purpose?
From what I have seen so far, most Spatial Statistics tools only work with densities, but they don´t seem to be applicable for track datasets.

Comment: Assuming these are lines you are talking about. Merge them together, planarise, build polygons. The area of polygons/length seems like a good criteria, e.g.=0 if lines coinside

Comment: In the end I didn´t need to be so accurate. Just a descriptive statistics histogram of the frequencies of LAt1-Lat2 and Lon1-Lon2 (absolute values) did the job. Thanks for your advice, I'll keep it in mind in case I need to use it!